# Formula for all first and second order predictors including interactions in R

Tags: r, formula

In the statistics programming language R, the following formula (e.g. in `lm()` or `glm()`)

```
z ~ (x+y)^2
```

is equivalent to

```
z ~ x + y + x:y
```

Assuming, I only have continuous predictors, is there a concise way to obtain

```
z ~ I(x^2) + I(y^2) + I(x) + I(y) + I(x*y)
```

A formula that does the right thing for factor predictors is a plus.

One possible solution is

```
z ~ (poly(x,2) + poly(y,2))^2
```

I am looking for something more elegant.

Comment: Is this a real question?

Comment: Richard, can you explain why you think the question is not real?  I have tried to clarify my question after your expression of doubt.

Comment: Someone has tagged this as homework.  I need this for work, not for homework.  I have added one solution to make it clear that I am not looking for a quick solution, but an elegant one.

Comment: I'm removing the homework tag. It's not clear to my why readers have beat you up. This seems legit and I asked a related question just last week.

Comment: In your first writing of this question, it was just a statement, with no question asked at all, but you have fixed it, so i will take away my down vote.

Comment: See the example in the help page for `cars`, but be aware that although the model is the same, the predictors aren't necessarily what you expect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if it is more elegant or not, but the poly function can take multiple vectors:

```
z ~ poly(x, y, degree=2)
```

This will create all the combinations that you asked for, without additional ones.  Do note that you need to specify degree=2, not just 2 when doing it this way.